# Make front <div> to react to mouse events but propagate them to lower elements too

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a moving background, composed by some layered images, that must react to mouse position changes. This big `<div>` is placed in the lowest level of my page, using `position:absolute`, `top: 0px` and a low `z-index`.

[image: first attempt]

You've probably already understood the first problem: initally, this `<div>` didn't get any mouse event when the cursor moves into one of the upper elements.

The first solution could be to set this CSS property to *every* front element: `pointer-events: none;`, but I really don't like it. How about the button? If I move the mouse on it, the background will move as espected, but the click will not be fired.

Secondary option, a mad trick: put another transparent `<div>` at the root of the page, at the same absolute position of the background, but with a very high `z-index`. It will listen to mouse coordinates and will transmit them to the moving background.

[image: second attempt]

Don't know what do you think about it, but it should work apart from a thing: this transparent layer captures the mouse events, but they aren't propagated to the lower texts and buttons, that continue to be "inactive". 
Is there a way to fix this behavior? Make the transparent listener to catch mouse events but also propagate them to every lower element (something like a "special" `pointer-events` rule).

Comment: Do you still have the problem, how did it turn out?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I still have this problem but I'm working on other things, I'll provide the JSFiddle very soon

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a JsFiddle?  I couldn't reproduce it  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhadesdev/4Y93k/30/) in this fiddle.

Making the button a link with a high z-index still allows the mouvemove event to be captured by an underlying div.

Would this solve the problem?

HTML:

```
<div id='movingBackground' class='moving-background' >

    <a class='button'>Button</a>

</div>

<div id='coordinates'>Coordinates get updated here on hover over div above</div>
```

CSS:

```
.moving-background {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;    
}

.button {
    position:absolute; 
    top:20px;    
    left:50px;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:20;     
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#movingBackground').on('mousemove',function(event) {
    $('#coordinates').text('X ' + event.pageX + ' - Y ' + event.pageY);
});
```